# Rails, Pagination offset not working, after clicking on '2' number(pagination) or other's page's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to pass offset in pagination.

```
  params[:page] = 1 if params[:page].nil?
  @pagination_count = (params[:pagination_count].present?) ? params[:pagination_count] : 50
  offset = ''
  if params[:page] != 1 
    offset = "limit 50 offset #{(params[:page].to_i - 1) * 50}"
  else
    offset = "limit 50"
  end
 posts_count =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query + ' where ' + query2 + query1).count 
 @posts =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query + ' where ' + query2 + query1 + offset).to_a.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50, total_entries: posts_count)
```

But, it's not working on click 2 page(pagination number), 2nd page is viewed but, data didn't get.
on 1st page data displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using both your own homebrew pagination (offset) and a gem for pagination. Your query returns 50 records (the correct ones on the 2nd page) and then the pagination gem tries to select the 2nd page from those 50. Of course there are no posts on the 2nd page in that case because all 50 are on the first page.

Use only one solution for pagination. Only homebrew (limit + offset you've done manually, remove `.paginate`) or only the gem (remove your offset query, use only `.paginate`)

Comment: I have tried that removing `.paginate` it's also not working,  finally, i have get count of total records, and passed to the view in `will-paginate` with `.paginate` method.

Comment: I still think the problem is what I described, but to help you further, I would need more info. For example what is query1 and query2. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure, I will go through this, and try to do my best. Thanks for that